# How to use Retrofit @Tag with Kotlin primitives?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2

I'm trying to use @Tag with Kotlin primitives.

```
  @POST("/api")
  suspend fun post(
    @Tag a: Boolean,
    @Tag b: Int? = null,
    ...
  )
```

However, when I call this function, I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to boolean
                            at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:1731)
                            at okhttp3.Request$Builder.tag(Request.kt:283)
                            at retrofit2.RequestBuilder.addTag(RequestBuilder.java:228)
                            at retrofit2.ParameterHandler$Tag.apply(ParameterHandler.java:446)
                            at retrofit2.RequestFactory.create(RequestFactory.java:129)

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to int
                            at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:1731)
                            at okhttp3.Request$Builder.tag(Request.kt:283)
                            at retrofit2.RequestBuilder.addTag(RequestBuilder.java:228)
                            at retrofit2.ParameterHandler$Tag.apply(ParameterHandler.java:446)
                            at retrofit2.RequestFactory.create(RequestFactory.java:129)
```

How can I use Retrofit @Tag with Kotlin primitives?

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-tag-retrofit-ahmad-shahwaiz/ you can look here.